# dillonkearns/elm-form Library

Tags: forms, elm

I started using the [dillonkearns/elm-form](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/dillonkearns/elm-form/3.0.0/) library in elm. It works well. Is it possible to create a dropdown where you can select multiple options using this library?

Thanks.

I tried modifying the [`Field.select`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/dillonkearns/elm-form/latest/Form-Field#select) option, but couldn't find a way to ensure the dropdown could select multiple options via checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to me that this is supported. I created [an Ellie demonstrating this scenario](https://ellie-app.com/nQZNRpPdZkDa1), and only one value is getting sent to the internal model. It doesn't appear that it's able to manage multiple values in the current setup.